# Is it possible to select text boxes with javaScript in acrobat

Tags: javascript, textbox, acrobat

I would like to be able to use the JavaScript function of one of my form inputs to be able to show or hide a text box. After a lot of research I can only find how to select and hide other form input methods.

here is what I have:

```js
var supplyBudget = this.getField("Supply Budget").value;
if (supplyBudget == ""){
/*text box selector*/.style.display = 3;
}
else if (supplyBudget =="0"){
/*text box selector*/.style.display = 3;
}
else{
/*text box selector*/.style.display = 1;
}
```

This runs when the user leaves the input field.

*edited code in accordance with  freginold's comment

Comment: thanks @freginold I'll fix those in the code snippet.

Comment: Your code is supposed to toggle between show/hide? What happens when you run it? Does one work but not the other, or neither works?

Comment: It doesn't do anything because I cannot find how to use the dom to select the texboxes I want to show/hide.

Comment: The easiest way to target them is to use their ID. See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide text that is part of the page content, you can't do that with PDF unless that particular text item is assigned to an Optional Content Group (OCG)... basically a layer that you can show or hide. There is no concept of "elements" for PDF page context like there is in HTML. Instead, there's a list of painting instructions for the page but JavaScript does not have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

There are no "selectors" in Acrobat JavaScript. However, you can get the number of fields and then iterate to get the names in order to find the ones that are of interest. For example if I wanted to hide all fields where the name starts with "name", I might write...

```
for ( var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++) {
    var field = this.getField(this.getNthFieldName(i));
    if ( field.name.indexOf("name") > -1 ) {
      field.display = display.hidden
    }
}
```

In general, to hide a field use...

```
this.getField("myFieldName").display = display.hidden;
```

To show a hidden field use...

```
this.getField("myFieldName").display = display.visible;
```

Comment: Thank you @joelgeraci. This does remove other question fields but not plain text like I was hoping. I am beginning to think it is simply impossible to hide plain text that is not an input field.

Comment: You want to hide text that is part of the page content? You can't do that with PDF unless that particular text item is assigned to an Optional Content Group (OCG)... basically a layer that you can show or hide. There is no concept of "elements" for PDF page context like there is in HTML. Instead, there's a list of painting instructions for the page but JavaScript does not have access to it.

Comment: Thanks Joel, could you repost that as an answer so I can select it please?

Answer (score -1):

The only way that I have found to "Hide plain Text" and a text field, is to use something similar to @joelgeraci answer. I had to add another empty read only textbox to cover the text and textbox to hide.

Such as:

```
this.getField("HiddenField").display = display.visible;
```

Then when I need to "show" the text and text box I would simply hide the hidden field:

```
this.getField("HiddenField").display = display.hidden;
```

I have multiple cases of this in a form that I have been creating for work and a lot of JS behind it. I am no expert, just learning as I go.